# ActionbarSherlock SearchView crash in android 4.x

Tags: actionbarsherlock, searchview

I'm using SearchView in ActionbarSherlock.
I't works correctly in android 2.3 but crash in android 4.x

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/provinceFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView>
```

and logic code

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
mSearchView = (SearchView)view.findViewById(R.id.provinceFilter);
mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
```